# Imports SAP.Middleware.Connector in visual Studio 2013 website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sap-dotnet-connector

I have created empty website of Visual Basic in visual studio 2013 and framework 4.0...

then add sapnco.dll and sapnco_utils.dll..

this DLL is 64 bit.

but not getting sap reference such as Imports SAP.Middleware.Connector

Plz plz plz anyone help me. I have spent too much time for this issue
[image]

Comment: How did you _add_ the dll files? As [a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: yes dll files are added as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you actually go through the tutorial since this is your first time, it will help you so you don't spend so much time.

You actually have to write some code and then ADD your using directives SAP.Middleware.Connector so that VS knows where to find the objects.

[image]

Later.............